# How to navigate through the chromium repository? More specifically where are the native implementations of JS APIs?

Tags: chromium

I am trying to navigate through the [Chromium repository](https://chromium.googlesource.com/) but it is a very large project and I have spent almost two days just trying to orient myself. Is there some common file that describes the layout of a project? Specifically, what I am trying to find is the Canvas's 2D context implementation for the android platform. Any direction is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend that you use Chromium Search Code web page that allows quickly search through Chromium source code online: https://cs.chromium.org/

As for the project layout you can take a look at: https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/getting-around-the-chrome-source-code

Comment: that chromium search page is definitely what I had in mind, I think every large project should have one of those. Thanks